# Make a bootstrap form, containing a button, appear inline next to another button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to move the "Delete page" button up next to the "View page" button. Is there an easy way to do this in bootstrap?

I don't want to wrap the h1 and "View page" button in the form, to preserve html readability.

```
<h1>
  Edit page
  <a target="_blank" class="btn btn-default" href="/view">View page</a>
  <form role="form">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Delete page" class="btn btn-danger btn btn-primary" data-confirm="Are you sure?" />
  </form>
</h1>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `display: inline` to your form :

```
form{
  display: inline;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ypkLaexL/

Comment: Thanks this is what I'm doing, but I thought maybe there would be some sort of helper class that applies this.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be to adjust your HTML.  Adding a class of `pull-right` to the form will cause it to align to the right margin of your `<h1>` tag, and placing the hyperlink inside the `<form>` will cause the button to align as per your desired results.

Added bonus; you're not creating a class that overrides Bootstraps form framework.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h1>
  Edit page
  
  <form role="form" class="pull-right">
    <a target="_blank" class="btn btn-default" href="/view">View page</a>
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Delete page" class="btn btn-danger btn btn-primary" data-confirm="Are you sure?" />
  </form>
</h1>
```